# Bizarre memory issue?

Tags: c, linux, memory, gcc

I'm having an interesting problem, which I hope is entirely my fault.

I have code which is reading from a queue, as in:

```
 do {
    evt       = &newevts[ evt_head++ ];
    evt_head &=  MAX_EVENTS;

    if (evt->index <= 0 || evt->index > MAX_INDEX) {
         printf("RX EVENT BAD NDX: ndx=%d h=%d\n",evt->index, evt_head);
         continue;
    }

    //... etc ...

 } while(evt_head != evt_tail) ;
```

The bizarre issue is the if statement can evaluate to evt->index being a bad value, but when the printf displays it shows a perfectly valid value! Example:

```
RX EVENT BAD NDX: ndx=1 h=64
```

The if statement clearly shows the condition must be <= 0 OR > 1024 (max index). To make matters worse, this only occurs once in a while. I'm using GCC, Centos 6.3. No threads touch evt_head except this thread. (I've renamed it a few times and re-compiled just to be sure.)

The tail is handled by a function which adds items to the queue in the same manner the head removes them (increment then AND). I have also added a counter inside the event structure itself to record the head/tail values as events are placed into the queue and find no lost or skipped values. It literally looks as though I'm getting some bad memory reads. But that's ridiculous - I'd expect system crashes or at least program crashes if that was the case.

Any ideas on how in the world this could be happening sporadically? (Frequency is about 1 out of 100 reads) I appreciate any input!

```
typedef struct {
    int    index;
    int    event;
} EVENT;

#define  MAX_EVENTS  0x01ff
#define  MAX_INDEX   1024
```

No threads or other code touches evt_head. Only this loop. The queue is never anywhere near full. I also happen to have a "SPIN LOCK" on entry to the routine which adds to the queue (in preparation for it being other-thread-accessed later), and an UNLOCK on exit.

Comment: For one, you're missing a third argument following your format string to `printf`.

Comment: Could you please show your definition of `MAX_EVENTS` and `newevts`?

Comment: Also, are you *sure* that `MAX_INDEX` is == 1024? Maybe we should see the `struct` definition that `evt` points to, also.

Comment: If the queue is being filled in one thread and emptied in another thread, you may be overwriting your event by accident because you modify `evt_head` before you use the data.  That may give the writing thread the impression that there's a free space in what is actually a full queue.

Comment: Are you sure `evt_head` is valid? What are you trying to do with the statement `evt_head &=  MAX_EVENTS;`? How else does `evt_head` get modified?

Comment: @Yaniv, he's jumping back to zero if `evt_head==MAX_EVENTS`, works because `MAX_EVENTS` is a 2^n-1.

Comment: Usual hints: Use the debugger `gdb`; compile with all warnings and debug info with `gcc -Wall -g`; perhaps look into preprocessor output `gcc -C -E`

Comment: If (evt_head == MAX_EVENTS) then after `evt_head &=  MAX_EVENTS;` makes evt_head == MAX_EVENTS.

Comment: @9dan and @Yaniv, sorry, I meant when `evt_head==MAX_EVENTS+1`.

Comment: 10 + 1 = 11 & 1ff = 11. 1ff + 1 = 200 & 1ff = 0. It's a circular index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the function adding events to your tail will change `evt_tail` before writing the `index` field. This allows your reader to access an event that is still in the process of being written.

Comment: Yes, I added a SPIN_LOCK around the event removal code and the issue went away. It had never been seen before: I'm sure this is because after I optimized a lot of code with ASM, it really sped it up and allowed this collision to occur. Prior to the optimizing, I guess the two were far enough apart in time that it never quite happened.

Comment: Without any spin lock in your reader, you could simply write the event first, and only then propagate the new value to `evt_tail`?

Comment: I thought about that, but then there's the possibility (I suppose) of the currently-in-use evt_head event still being accessed. You've definitely hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Unless you also increment `evt_head` only at the very end and at the `continue` condition of the read loop. Protects you in case of a full queue as well. If both `evt_head` and `evt_tail` are incremented only after completion of the respective operation, you are guaranteed to be fine without a spin lock in your reader.

Comment: Maybe someone else could comment on this but I think we have a case here where memory fences are needed as well.

Comment: s.bandara: you're right. I was up entirely too late last night and was getting foggy. I have implemented it as you stated. Thanks for your help!